# How to clear up the certain columns of the same title generated by Django

Tags: python, jquery, django, tags

I am trying to display some records generated by Django. If it has same title, it only displays certain fields, not all of them.

```
#html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
   <td>Title</td>
   <td>First name</td>
   <td>Last name</td>
   <td>Favourites</td>
   <td>Pets</td>
  </tr>
{% for item in items %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ item.user.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.user.first name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.user.last name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.fruit }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.pets }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
...


#views.py
def items(request, id):
  itemList = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=id)
  ...
  render(request, 'items.html', {'items': itemList, ...})
```

If the title is the same, I want to display first name, last name once such as

```
title-1, Henry Wattson, Apple, Peach
                        Cat, Dog
title-2, Sarah Smith, Banana, Strawberry
                      Hamspter, Parrot
```

How can I do in Django, if not possible, in JQuery?

Comment: Please add the view which is rendering this html.

Comment: From where are you getting `title, first name, last name, item_1, item_2` in the context?

Comment: It is getting from the Item model which is straightforward, so I didn't add it here. The fields are nothing particular to be characterized. Is it needed above?

Comment: In your `items(request, id)` you are only getting one object of Item. Why you are using loop on items?

Comment: I forgot to add models' relationships. The Item model is in many-to-one relationships with User.

Comment: In your method items(request, id): you are retrieving only one Item with get_object_or_404(). Note that get_list_or_404() exists, but you mustn't give it the attribute 'pk=' or you will get only one again..